# Ext.Ajax.extraParams: Add a new parameter sent by default

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs7

I have a bigger application written with ExtJs 7. Now I need to add an extra-Parameter to all ajax-calls and ajax-store-calls from a certain point on.

To change all ajax-calls and all stores would be a lot of work, so the idea is to define an override or prototype, and all calls done after that should use the new parameter.

I tried:

```
Ext.override(Ext.Ajax, { extraParams: {myNewParam:'New Param' }});
```

and

```
Ext.Ajax.extraParams = 
{   myNewParam:'New Param'
};
```

and

```
Ext.Ajax.prototype.extraParams = 
{   myNewParam:'New Param'
};
```

but myNewParam is either not transmitted or I get JavaScript errors.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you need but this is one possibility.

You can use an event listener attached to `Ext.Ajax` that is executed before every request. There is a `beforerequest` event, check the [documentation here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/modern/Ext.Ajax.html#event-beforerequest).

Find a place in your application that runs once, for example in your `Application.js`. Add this:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function(conn, options, eOpts) {

});
```

You need to determine somehow wether you need the new extra param for this particular request.

Within the above function, all request options are in the `options` parameter. For example you have the URL in `options.url` and the parameters within `options.params`.

So you can add you extra param like:

```
options.params.myNewParam = 'New Param';
```

(You can do many other things here, for example you can cancel the request with `return false;` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```
Ext.define('ModernApp.overrides.Ajax', {
    override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    extraParams: {
        myNewParam: 'New Param'
    },
});
```

That way you will overwrite everywhere you are using a proxy.Ajax

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass parameter through all requests is **Headers**

```
Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({ 'MyToken': 'aeu73nELpf73nsDHDyez'});
```